# Perl: String to Scalar variable

Tags: perl

Could someone help me with the following:
I want to extract the numerical values from the input file and perform mathematical operations.

Input file sample

```
    string txt
    text0 = 40,
    text1 = 2;
    string text1 txt
```

I want to collect text0 and text1 into variables with the same name and

print "$text0/text1";

at the end of the file reading. Please note that the text1 is part of the string of other part of the file and need to be ignored.

I was working with this code but fails because of the "text1" in other parts of the code,

```
   while (<PH>) {
chomp;
if ($_ =~ "text0") {
    my $data = $_;
    my @temp = split (' ', $data);
    $text0 = $temp[2];
    $text0 =~ s/,//;
}
if ($_ =~ "text1") {
    my $data = $_;
    my @temp = split (' ', $data);
    $text1 = $temp[2];
    $text1 =~ s/;//;

}
    }
  my $final = $text0/text1;
  print "$final\n";
```

Any improvement to my basic code would also be appriciated.

regards

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, you need to put an anchor for "start of line" (which is a caret) in your match test:

```
if ($_ =~ "^text0") {
```

and

```
if ($_ =~ "^text1") {
```

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will read your input line by line, and assign any digits following `text0 =` to a variable `$text1` if a match is found, and the same for `text1`. It then prints both variables outside the loop:

```
use warnings;
use strict; 

open my $input, '<', 'in.txt';

my ($text1, $text2);
while(<$input>){
    chomp;
    ($text1) = $1 if /text0 = (\d+)/;
    ($text2) = $1 if /text1 = (\d+)/;
}

print "Text0 = $text1\nText1 = $text2\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne '$1==1?(print $a/$2):($a=$2) if(/text([0-1]) = ([\d]+)/);' your_file
```